# Remove specific value index based on input

Tags: php, arrays

How do I remove an element from an array when I know the elements name? for example:

I have an array:

```
[troli] => Array (
    [fruit] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [name] => apple
            [foo] => bar
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [name] => banana
            [foo] => bar
            )
        )
    [vegetables] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [name] => tomatoes
            [foo] => bar
            )
        [1] => Array (
            [name] => asparagus
            [foo] => bar
            )
        )
    )
```

1. the user enters `apple`

`[troli][fruit][0]` is removed.

2. the user enters `asparagus`

`[troli][vegetables][1]` is removed.

Comment: What have you tried to get this going? Showing your attempts might help us understand your needs better :)

Comment: Also, can you precise on your usecase if it should remove the first occurence ? each one ? A certain one ?

Comment: I want to create a functions that disable same fruit/vegetables more than 1 in troli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_filter` function:

```
$arr = ['troli' => Array(
    'fruit' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'name' => 'apple'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'name' => 'banana'
        )
    ),
    'vegetables' => Array(
        0 => Array(
            'name' => 'tomatoes'
        ),
        1 => Array(
            'name' => 'asparagus'
        )
    )
)];

$itemToRemove = "asparagus";
foreach ($arr['troli'] as $k => &$v) {
    $v = array_filter($v, function($v) use($itemToRemove){ 
        return $v['name'] != $itemToRemove; 
    });
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save Null at its place and then use array_filter on it to remove null data. Store the result in the variable you want.

For this case use foreach to run a loop. Check if the value matches the input value. If match replace it with null and apply array_filter().